# Aligning a cycle in LaTeX

Tags: alignment, latex, theory, cycle

I want to create a cycle like this in LaTeX:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/c/8/0c814b6d3ade0dfd8ea4408af6e07ac6.png

Instead of numbers I want to have b1,b2,...,b9 and m1,m2,...,m9.
This is the code I use:
`\pi_0 = \binom{b_1\ b_2\ b_3\ b_4\ b_5\ b_6\ b_7\ b_8\ b_9}{m_1\ m_2\ m_3\ m_4\ m_5\ m_6\ m_7\ m_8\ m_9}`

But it does not produced the desired result, as the b-s and m-s are not aligned (I want for them to be exactly one above the other):

[image]

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `array` environment to produce a matrix:

```
\pi_0 = \left(
            \begin{array}{cccc}
                b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\
                m_1 & m_2 & m_3 & m_4
            \end{array}
        \right)
```

By the way, there is a [separate StackExchange site for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have not been aware of the StackExchange site for LaTeX before. The cycle display does look a lot better now. Thanks very much!